# Card.io: is there an opportunity to launch camera activity only?

Tags: android, credit-card, scanning, card.io

Can I launch card.io's camera activity only? And then get back to my custom activity with manual entry to edit card info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you set [EXTRA_SUPPRESS_MANUAL_ENTRY](http://card-io.github.io/card.io-Android-SDK/io/card/payment/CardIOActivity.html#EXTRA_SUPPRESS_MANUAL_ENTRY) to `true`, you will not see the card.io manual entry activity.